# Merge Duplicate list entries into one and display quantity in C#

Tags: c#

I have a list as below.

```
List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();
```

And the Product class looks as follows.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now if the user inserts duplicate list entries identified by ID, how will I be able to merge it as follows

```
Product Name       Qty
Coke                2
Pepsi               7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use LINQ to build a new set of products:

```
var results = productList
                 .GroupBy(p => p.ID)
                 .Select(g => new Product { ID = g.Key, ProductName = g.First().ProductName, Quantity = g.Sum(i => i.Quantity) })
                 .ToList();
```

If you just need the product names and Quantities, you can use:

```
var results = productList
                 .GroupBy(p => p.ProductName)
                 .Select(g => new { ProductName = g.Key, Quantity = g.Sum() });

foreach(var product in results)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}      {1}", product.ProductName, product.Quantity);
}
```

Comment: This is slightly wrong. If the quantity is already more than one, this will give you wrong results.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Good point - just fixed for that scenario

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = productList.GroupBy(p => p.ID)
                        .Select(g => new Product { 
                            ProductName = g.First().ProductName, 
                            Quantity = g.Sum(p => p.Quantity) });
```